# Assigning button and key press to same event

Tags: javascript, function, events

I am making a to do list in JavaScript where I want to add an item to the list when I press the Add button or hit enter. I have the button click working, but I can't get the enter to work to do the same task.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new task">
  <span onclick="addToList()" class="addBtn">Add!</span>
```

My addToList function:

```
function addToList() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("Please input a value");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("X");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I have it onclick for my button. I tried to use onkeypress for the input but it doesn't work. I also tried onkeydown and selecting the enter button:

```
<input onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        document.getElementById('addBtn').click()" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new task">
```

But this also didn't work.

How can I edit my existing addToList function to also add an item on Enter? Or is it better to create a completely new function for that?

Comment: you can change the inline if condition to seperate function onkeydown="functionName()"

Answer (score 1):

Html form will take care of submitting it when click enter

```
<form onsubmit="addToList()">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new task">
  <button class="addBtn" type="submit">Add!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new task">
<span onclick="addToList()" id="addBtn">Add! (be carefull you wrote addBtn class)</span>




document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
      
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById('addBtn').click()"
      }
    
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) makes your life so much easier ... Rewritten/-factored your code to this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", documentWideHandler);
document.addEventListener("keyup", documentWideHandler);
document.addEventListener("focusin", documentWideHandler);

function documentWideHandler(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  // action depends on the event and/or origin characteristics
  if (evt.type === "focusin" &&
      origin.id === "myInput") {
    return document.querySelector("#warn").textContent = "";
  }
  if (evt.type === "keyup" &&
      origin.id === "myInput" &&
      evt.key === "Enter" || // note: event.keyCode is deprecated
      origin.classList.contains("addBtn")) {
    return addToList();
  }
  if (origin.classList.contains("close")) {
    // removing seems more applicable
    return origin.closest("li").remove();
  }
}

function addToList() {
  const inputElem = document.querySelector("#myInput");
  // typically this is the first thing you do
  // so you don't have to do anything else if
  // the input is not provided
  if (!inputElem.value.trim().length) {
    // more user friendly 'alert'
    return document.querySelector("#warn")
      .textContent = "Please enter a task!";
  }
  
  // using insertAdjacentHTML
  document.querySelector("#myUl").insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, 
    `<li><span class="close"></span>${inputElem.value}</li>`);
  
  // typically this would be the last thing to do
  inputElem.value = "";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

.addBtn,
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -2rem;
}

.close:before {
  content: "\274c";
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}

#warn {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new task">
<span class="addBtn">Add!</span>
<span id="warn"></span>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```